# Why are there two if's on single line conditional?

Tags: ruby

I am very very new to ruby. Could anyone decode this for me?

```
page = 1 if page <= 0 if @type != 'something'
```

My guess is something like:

```
if (page <= 0 && @type != 'something')
then page = 1
```

Comment: That's a really bad habit to get into, and whomever wrote this should feel bad. That's just plain confusing.

Comment: Agreed, I think `page = 1 if type != 'something' && page <=0` would be much better.

Answer (score 4):

Your rewritting:

```
if (page <= 0 && @type != 'something')
```

is close, but is not correct. Your original line would be interpreted as:

```
(page = 1 if page <= 0) if @type != 'something'
```

which means that `@type != 'something'` is first evaluated, and the rest is shortcut if the condition is falsy at that point. This means your original line can be rewritten as:

```
if (@type != 'something' && page <= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify a little further. If @type != 'something' is falsy then page would just have the value it had before this statement. Is that a correct assumption

Answer (score 4):

another way to understand it, is just to break it down statement by statement

```
doThis if doThat
```

Is the same as writing

```
if doThat
  doThis
end
```

so...

```
page = 1 if page <= 0 if @type != 'something'
```

is

```
if @type != 'something'
  if page <= 0
    page = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! that makes a lot more sense to me.